# How can I SSH remotely into my linux VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, ssh, virtual-machine

I am trying to remotely access a virtual box remotely. Because this is a virtualbox hosted on a windows machine, it does not have it's own IP address to use for SSH login. I have tried changing the network settings to Bridge Adapter to get an IP, but nothing has worked. Are there some steps I am missing, or what else can I do to SSH into the box? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were using the `NAT` mode before and you have no reason to change it other then the SSH, you can do it in that mode. Just expand the advanced settings in the network configuration and create a port forwarding rule for the port 22. Then you will be able to SSH to the VM by using the host's ip address.

Comment: it says you need a guest IP to make a rule like this

Comment: Are you sure? In my system it lets me create such a rule leaving the guest ip field blank.

Comment: Yes it says "The current port forwarding rules are not valid. None of the host or guest port values may be set to zero." This is with the host info filled in and guest blank

Comment: Yes, you have to set the guest & host _ports_. Use 22 from the guest port and whatever you like for the host port. Then to ssh to the VM, you would have to ssh to the _host port_.